# Switch scene after end of sequence

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I've got an cocos2d-x javascript project with a "splash screen" scene (logos etc). After the end of the last sequence I want to switch automatically to the next scene.

How is this possible? Can I add something to the sequence? Or how do I use `isDone()` to check when I have to call `cc.director.runScene(new mySecondScene())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add another action to your sequence (an instant action). This fits the purpose perfectly

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/js/v3x/symbols/cc.CallFunc.html
Using the code you've provided in the post:

```
function nextScene(){
  cc.director.runScene(new mySecondScene());
}

var switchToTheNextScene= new cc.CallFunc(nextScene, this);
var sequence2 = new cc.Sequence(sequence, switchToTheNextScene);
someNode.runAction(sequence2);
```

Also, an off-topic advice - you can wrap the scene in a cc.TransitionScene subclass to make your splashscreen disappear in a cool way. No sequences are included
Something like:

```
    cc.director.runScene(cc.TransitionFade(0.8, new mySecondScene()) );
```

Where 0.8 is the transition time. Again, check the [docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/js/v3x/) for cc.TransitionScene subclasses, cocos 2d js has a lot of them